# Salesforce Validation Rule ensuring field contains no 'PO Box' or 'P.O. Box'

Tags: regex, validation, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have a requirement to create a validation rule to ensure that a salesforce field on custom object Address__c does not contain  'PO Box' or 'P.O. Box'. Can someone please let me know the suitable regex function to do that?

Comment: `^(?!.*P\.?O\.? BOX).*` https://regex101.com/r/jS0iI1/1

Comment: Thanks. I am new to REGEX use can you please tell me if I have to put it in salesforce validation rule like this.                                    REGEX(Name,"^(?!.*P\.?O\.? BOX).*")

Comment: escape the backslash one more time if necessary.

Comment: It is not working here. I have put this:             REGEX(Name,"^(?!.*P\.?O\.?BOX\).*")                                   It gives error in syntax

Comment: Can you please check the same at your end?

Comment: did you mean this https://regex101.com/r/jS0iI1/6 ?

Comment: I mean to say validation rule in salesforce org.

Comment: Sorry i don't know the code.